# Whether to say: "l'un de l'autre" or l'une de l'autre"

Tags: pronoms, accord, coordination

> **La tête** et **le corps** ne font qu'un. On ne peut dissocier **l'une** de **l'autre** et quand on subit moralement, le physique craque...

I wonder if "l'un(e)" ought to correspond to the noun placed first: in the given sentence, to the feminine "la tête", or to the masculine "le corps" if the two nouns were in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

The order matters here and allows the feminine for the first pronoun. However, the masculine is possible too in this case

> ***La** tête et **le** corps ne font qu'un. On ne peut dissocier l'**un** de l'autre...*

The feminine is unlikely to be used and possibly not grammatical when the first substantive is masculine and the second feminine, although the old [rule of proximity](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_proximit%C3%A9) would have allowed it<sup>1</sup>. I haven't found occurrences of such a case.

The feminine is mandatory if both substantives are feminine:

> *Ici, l'on ne s'intéresse pas à la Nature pour elle-même et l'on tend à placer **Nature** et **Révélation** seulement en regard l'**une** de l'autre...*

Here are some examples where the feminine is not carried out:

> *[Le citoyen de Tocqueville: Non, messieurs, **la** démocratie et **le** socialisme ne sont pas solidaires l’**un** de l’autre.](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/%C5%92uvres_compl%C3%A8tes_d%E2%80%99Alexis_de_Tocqueville,_L%C3%A9vy/Discours_%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99Assembl%C3%A9e_constituante_sur_la_question_du_droit_au_travail)*
>
> *Que **la** pensée et **le** langage aient besoin l'**un** de l'autre...*

<sup>1</sup> There is an ongoing effort to reestablish this rule.

Comment: As my french teacher once said... French is a sexist language, masculine always wins.

Comment: @Karlyr Don't shoot the messenger though ;-)  I believe this characteristic is shared by most if not all Romance languages. I also find somewhat funny that fighting some sexist aspects of the language can be done in English by avoiding the usage of gendered job names like *stewardess, actress, poetess* to neutral *flight attendant* or male names *actor, poet* while, to achieve the same goal, the trend in French is on the opposite to create or revive female job titles like *auteure, docteure, écrivaine...*

Comment: @jiliagre It was just a way to make us remember that ;) Which works, 18 years later xD